Issues running python using Intergrated Terminal in Visual Studio
My default, Windows Python interpreter is installed in C:\Program Files. Because of various constraints, I can't change this location.
When I try running python in Visual Studio Code using the integrated terminal, it throws an error like the following:
c:\Program: The term 'c:\Program' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...
I assume the space in the path is the issue.
Would be very appreciative if someone has found a workaround.

Check your configuration for the integrated terminal that gets used in VS Code in the VS Code documentation Terminal Profiles, other similar question Unable to run typescript build task: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command shows a similar error but for different programming language, maybe helpful explaining fixing the path for your terminal.

This problem is usually caused by spaces in your python interpreter path.
You have to check the path to the Python interpreter in your settings.json file in VS Code.
You can do the following steps to reset it:

Open the Command Palette by shortcuts Ctrl+Shift+P.
Open your user settings.json by typing Preferences: Open User Settings.
Search for python.defaultInterpreterPath and reset the value to the path to your Python interpreter.

